# Default value to a data parameter , SSRS

Tags: date, reporting-services, parameters, default-value

In my SSRS report I wanted to default the date parameter with the execution date. I default the date patameter with `=DateValue(Globals!ExecutionTime)`
or `=today`. I do have 5 other parameters in my report.

In reporting manager, it makes the page refresh each time when I select another parameter value. Why is that? How do I solve this?

Comment: Check out this blog [post](http://sqlreportingservices.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!17F39A64B3FF4C5C!238.entry)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps somebody still in need.

To avoid refreshes on changing parameters, avoid using expressions in the Parameter default values.

For example, instead of specifying `=TODAY()` expression, create a dataset with a SQL query such as `SELECT getdate() = DefaultDate` and from the parameter, refer to this dataset using query for your default value.

check these out:

http://blog.summitcloud.com/2009/12/fix-refresh-of-parameters-in-ssrs/

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/6e5c4137-092f-4d54-a1a1-27730744074d/

Hope it helps.